# FFmpeg Ubuntu linker error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ffmpeg, g++

I am trying to decode audio using ffmpeg lib and c++ from Ubuntu 12.04. I am following the code here https://0xdeafc0de.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/ffmpeg-audio-playback-sample/

Below is the command used to compile the code

```
g++ -std=c++11 decode_play_audio.cpp -I/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/include -L/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib  -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil
```

But getting the compile error as below,

I have build latest ffmpeg 3.0 and located at `/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/`

And I can see all the libs located at `/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib`

```
  libavcodec.a
  libavfilter.a
  libavutil.a
  libswresample.a
  pkgconfig
  libavdevice.a
  libavformat.a
  libpostproc.a
  libswscale.a
```

**Error:**

```
decode_play_audio.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
decode_play_audio.cpp:169:9: warning: ‘void av_free_packet(AVPacket*)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4040) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         av_free_packet(&packet);
         ^
decode_play_audio.cpp:169:31: warning: ‘void av_free_packet(AVPacket*)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4040) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         av_free_packet(&packet);
                               ^
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dvenc.o): In function `dv_init_mux':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dvenc.c:344: undefined reference to `av_dv_codec_profile2'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(matroskaenc.o): In function `get_aac_sample_rates':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskaenc.c:612: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(matroskaenc.o): In function `put_xiph_codecpriv':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskaenc.c:535: undefined reference to `avpriv_split_xiph_headers'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(movenc.o): In function `handle_eac3':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:347: undefined reference to `avpriv_ac3_parse_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:397: undefined reference to `avpriv_ac3_parse_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(movenc.o): In function `mov_get_rawvideo_codec_tag':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(movenc.o): In function `mov_find_codec_tag':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(movenc.o): In function `mov_get_rawvideo_codec_tag':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(movenc.o):/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/movenc.c:1383: more undefined references to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov' follow
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): In function `swf_read_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/swfdec.c:364: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): In function `swf_read_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/swfdec.c:153: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): In function `zlib_refill':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/swfdec.c:121: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): In function `swf_read_close':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/swfdec.c:529: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/tmp/cc18cojo.o: In function `main':
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `ao_initialize'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `ao_default_driver_id'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `ao_open_live'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `ao_play'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x639): undefined reference to `ao_play'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `ao_play'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x729): undefined reference to `ao_play'
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x831): undefined reference to `ao_play'
/tmp/cc18cojo.o:decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x8ed): more undefined references to `ao_play' follow
/tmp/cc18cojo.o: In function `main':
decode_play_audio.cpp:(.text+0x961): undefined reference to `ao_shutdown'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(frame_thread_encoder.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_encoder_free':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/frame_thread_encoder.c:236: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(frame_thread_encoder.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_encoder_init':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/frame_thread_encoder.c:211: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_free':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:566: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_init':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:706: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_slice.o): In function `ff_slice_thread_free':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/pthread_slice.c:116: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_slice.o): In function `ff_slice_thread_init':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavcodec/pthread_slice.c:231: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(allformats.o): In function `av_register_all':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/allformats.c:59: undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(async.o): In function `async_close':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/async.c:313: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(async.o): In function `async_open':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/async.c:281: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(avidec.o): In function `avi_extract_stream_metadata':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/avidec.c:411: undefined reference to `avpriv_exif_decode_ifd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(avienc.o): In function `avi_write_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/avienc.c:363: undefined reference to `avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_avi'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(concatdec.o): In function `detect_stream_specific':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/concatdec.c:200: undefined reference to `av_bitstream_filter_init'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(concatdec.o): In function `filter_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/concatdec.c:502: undefined reference to `av_bitstream_filter_filter'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dnxhddec.o): In function `dnxhd_probe':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dnxhddec.c:33: undefined reference to `avpriv_dnxhd_parse_header_prefix'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dtsdec.o): In function `dts_probe':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dtsdec.c:72: undefined reference to `avpriv_dca_convert_bitstream'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dtsdec.c:89: undefined reference to `avpriv_dca_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dv.o): In function `dv_frame_offset':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dv.c:425: undefined reference to `av_dv_codec_profile2'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dv.o): In function `dv_read_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dv.c:529: undefined reference to `av_dv_frame_profile'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(dv.o): In function `avpriv_dv_produce_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/dv.c:375: undefined reference to `av_dv_frame_profile'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(flacdec.o): In function `flac_read_timestamp':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/flacdec.c:251: undefined reference to `av_parser_init'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/flacdec.c:266: undefined reference to `av_parser_parse2'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/flacdec.c:282: undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(http.o): In function `http_close':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/http.c:1424: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(http.o): In function `parse_content_encoding':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/http.c:626: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/http.c:627: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/http.c:632: undefined reference to `zlibCompileFlags'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(http.o): In function `http_buf_read_compressed':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/http.c:1209: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(id3v2.o): In function `id3v2_parse':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/id3v2.c:963: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(isom.o): In function `ff_mp4_read_dec_config_descr':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/isom.c:493: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/isom.c:497: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_freq_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(latmenc.o): In function `latm_decode_extradata':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:63: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(latmenc.o): In function `latm_write_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:197: undefined reference to `avpriv_copy_bits'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:199: undefined reference to `avpriv_align_put_bits'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(latmenc.o): In function `latm_write_frame_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:123: undefined reference to `avpriv_copy_bits'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:130: undefined reference to `avpriv_copy_pce_data'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:119: undefined reference to `avpriv_copy_bits'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(latmenc.o): In function `latm_write_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/latmenc.c:195: undefined reference to `avpriv_copy_bits'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(matroskadec.o): In function `matroska_decode_buffer':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1294: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1309: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1312: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1327: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressInit'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1342: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompress'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1345: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1302: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1335: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(matroskadec.o): In function `matroska_aac_sri':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(matroskadec.o):/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1616: more undefined references to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates' follow
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_cmov':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mov.c:3807: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_dac3':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mov.c:744: undefined reference to `avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_dec3':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mov.c:779: undefined reference to `avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3dec.o): In function `mp3_read_probe':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:85: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3dec.o): In function `check':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:438: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:438: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:438: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3dec.o): In function `mp3_parse_vbr_tags':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:303: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3dec.o):/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3dec.c:438: more undefined references to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header' follow
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3enc.o): In function `mp3_write_xing':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:149: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_freq_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:149: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_freq_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:149: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_freq_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3enc.o):/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:179: more undefined references to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab' follow
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mp3enc.o): In function `mp3_write_xing':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mp3enc.c:195: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpegaudio_decode_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(mxfenc.o): In function `mxf_parse_dnxhd_frame':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mxfenc.c:1677: undefined reference to `avpriv_dnxhd_get_frame_size'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/mxfenc.c:1679: undefined reference to `avpriv_dnxhd_get_interlaced'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(nutenc.o): In function `find_expected_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/nutenc.c:73: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_freq_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/nutenc.c:76: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpa_bitrate_tab'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggenc.o): In function `ogg_write_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggenc.c:517: undefined reference to `avpriv_split_xiph_headers'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggparsedirac.o): In function `dirac_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsedirac.c:40: undefined reference to `av_dirac_parse_sequence_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggparseflac.o): In function `old_flac_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparseflac.c:86: undefined reference to `av_parser_init'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparseflac.c:97: undefined reference to `av_parser_parse2'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparseflac.c:101: undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggparsevorbis.o): In function `vorbis_cleanup':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:257: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_free'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggparsevorbis.o): In function `vorbis_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:421: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_reset'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:424: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_frame_flags'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:436: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_frame_flags'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:461: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_reset'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:466: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_frame_flags'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(oggparsevorbis.o): In function `vorbis_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/oggparsevorbis.c:391: undefined reference to `av_vorbis_parse_init'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(rtmpproto.o): In function `rtmp_uncompress_swfplayer':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtmpproto.c:1077: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtmpproto.c:1087: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtmpproto.c:1105: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(rtpdec_jpeg.o): In function `jpeg_create_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:147: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_dc'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:147: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_dc_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:149: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_dc'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:149: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_dc_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:151: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_ac_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:151: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_ac_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:153: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_ac_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpdec_jpeg.c:153: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_ac_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(rtpenc_jpeg.o): In function `ff_rtp_send_jpeg':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:104: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_dc_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:105: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_dc'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:140: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_ac_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:141: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_ac_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:116: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_dc_chrominance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:117: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_dc'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:128: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_bits_ac_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/rtpenc_jpeg.c:129: undefined reference to `avpriv_mjpeg_val_ac_luminance'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(sdp.o): In function `xiph_extradata2config':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:367: undefined reference to `avpriv_split_xiph_headers'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(sdp.o): In function `latm_context2config':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: undefined reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(sdp.o):/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/sdp.c:457: more undefined references to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_sample_rates' follow
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(spdifdec.o): In function `spdif_get_offset_and_codec':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/spdifdec.c:60: undefined reference to `avpriv_aac_parse_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(spdifenc.o): In function `spdif_header_aac':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/spdifenc.c:357: undefined reference to `avpriv_aac_parse_header'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(spdifenc.o): In function `spdif_header_dts':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/spdifenc.c:258: undefined reference to `avpriv_dca_sample_rates'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(takdec.o): In function `tak_read_header':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/takdec.c:145: undefined reference to `avpriv_tak_parse_streaminfo'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(tee.o): In function `close_slaves':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/tee.c:327: undefined reference to `av_bitstream_filter_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(tee.o): In function `parse_bsfs':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/tee.c:115: undefined reference to `av_bitstream_filter_init'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(tee.o): In function `close_slaves':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/tee.c:327: undefined reference to `av_bitstream_filter_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(udp.o): In function `udp_close':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/udp.c:974: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/udp.c:975: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(udp.o): In function `udp_open':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/udp.c:847: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o): In function `free_stream':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:3710: undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o): In function `has_decode_delay_been_guessed':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:863: undefined reference to `avpriv_h264_has_num_reorder_frames'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:863: undefined reference to `avpriv_h264_has_num_reorder_frames'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:863: undefined reference to `avpriv_h264_has_num_reorder_frames'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o): In function `parse_packet':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:1257: undefined reference to `av_parser_parse2'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:1318: undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/build_Mar-10-2016/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o): In function `ff_read_frame_flush':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavformat/utils.c:1669: /lib/libavutil.a(time.o): In function `av_gettime_relative':
/home/codeDev/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.0/libavutil/time.c:60: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It looks like you're not linking with everything required.

Comment: I linked with all the library available on ffmpeg lib directory in following order `-lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample  -lavdevice  -lpostproc  -lswscale` but still the error.

Comment: Start with the first undefined reference, `av_dv_codec_profile2`. Find out what you need to link to get that. And so on. Note also that with g++ the order that libraries are specified, can be significant.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding more linker option like  `-lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample  -lavdevice  -lpostproc -lao -lz -lx264 -llzma -lbz2 -lva -lrt`, anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: post this as an answer and close it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding more linker option like `-lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice -lpostproc -lao -lz -lx264 -llzma -lbz2 -lva -lrt`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some link library, my test code:

```
//testFFmpeg.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello ffmpeg\n");
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open input failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "find stream info failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int videoStream = av_find_best_stream(pFormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);

    printf("nb:%d, url:%s, time:%ld, duration:%ld, bitRate:%ld, videoStream:%d\n", 
            pFormatCtx->nb_streams, pFormatCtx->url, pFormatCtx->start_time, pFormatCtx->duration, 
            pFormatCtx->bit_rate, videoStream);
    return 0;
}
```

my compile command:

```
gcc testFFmpeg.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswresample -lz -llzma -lpthread -lm -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
```